# Python selenium, access div class, iframe style

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to get that `src="http://example1.com"` link

```
<div class="video">
  <iframe style="border: none;" src="http://example1.com" width="100%" height="460" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #428bca; color: #fff; margin-top: 20px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px;padding: 8px;">Description
  <a style="color:yellow; font-weight: bold" href="http://example.com">Text</a>
</div>
```

I tried with

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='video']")
for elem in elems:
    print elem.get_attribute("src")
```

or:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('video').get_attribute('src')
print element
```

And many others but seems nothing is working or I find "none"
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `src="http://example1.com"` is not in the `<div>` with `class='video'`, but in its child `<iframe>` element

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.video > iframe')
print iframe.get_attribute('src')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to get is in `iframe` tag so you need to add in your xpath and try

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='video']/iframe").get_attribute('src')
print element
```